# How to submit ModalWindow in Wicket without showing warning prompt?

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, modal-dialog, wicket, required

I have form in ModalWindow which I want to submit it. Is it possible to stop showing the alert "Really leave web" kind and waiting for user confirmation?

I dont want to use the FeedbackPanel. I would like to use standard HTML5 required messages e.g. from Chrome to form fields, but when everything required is successfully filled, I dont want to show to user the implicit wicket alert message.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the unload confirmation:

```
window.showUnloadConfirmation(false);
```